# yum install php-pear* on centos

Tags: php, linux, centos, pear, yum

I'm trying to install pear on my centos.

I've used "*yum install php-pear**" to install pear and it seemed to install with success. No errors. I restart my server.

However when I check out phpinfo(). I see that my php is still built using "*--without-pear*".

Isn't yum supposed to rebuild my php with pear? What would be possibly going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like

```
$ pear list
```

and

```
$ pear info PEAR
```

- now if you get a listing of installed packages in the first case and information on what version of pear is installed in the second you're ready to use it.

Answer (score 4):

The output of `phpinfo()` is correct; the binary *was* built without PEAR. Fortunately what it says there doesn't matter. Look into the sections below to see what is currently available.

Answer (score 1):

yum does not rebuild anything. It downloads the necessary software modules and installs it on your machine. Your stock centos php does not have pear pre-compiled, but it will still be able to use pear once you've downloaded your modules.

If you cannot run pear, make sure you have the executable included in your path, or use "locate" to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You might still need to configure PEAR, did you check the [PEAR site](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, I have installed the given packages and restarted the server.

Try this
yum install php-pear php-gd php-pear-DB -y
service httpd restart.

it works