# Nginx not running php files after pear install

Tags: php, linux, nginx, centos, pear

I installed Nginx & PHP using this guide here:

[Nginx install guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7#step-four-%E2%80%94-configure-nginx-to-process-php-pages)

```
yum install php php-mysql php-fpm
```

edited /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
listen.owner = nobody
listen.group = nobody
listen.owner = nobody
listen.group = nobody
```

ran:

```
systemctl start php-fpm
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  <my servers IP here - removed>;

# note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

I then tested

```
http://<my server ip>/phpinfo.php
```

**and it worked!**

I then installed pear

```
yum install php-pear
```

but now php files don't work, the browser tries to download them instead of running them.

I've tried:

1. rebooting the server
2. restarting nginx
3. restarting php-fpm
4. checking all the config files to make sure they as the same as above.

I'm completely stuck. I don't know what to check to get php work again. This is the first time I've installed Nginx. I've looked around on the net for answers and on here.

I'm running Centos 7

help :)

UPDATE:

I've tried a much more shortened config file:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  <my servers IP here - removed>;

# note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

but that didn't work either.

I also tried:

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

instead of:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
```

but that didn't work too.

**UPDATE 2**

i found out that if I go to:

http://my ip/phpinfo.php - **it works!**

but if I go to:

http://domainname/phpinfo.php - it tries to download the PHP file instead of running it.

How do I make php files run while using the domain name instead of the IP?

Comment: I tried to uninstall pear - yum uninstall php-pear but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: I tried uninstalling a re-installing nginx & php but it still doesn't process php files

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: If I remember well, I faced this issue some times ago. I don't remember how I resolved it but I think logs helped me. Try to do a `tail -f` on your log(s) file(s) (nginx + php) to see exactly what is happening when you call your page: it may be a problem coming from php-fpm.

Comment: I found out that php files run when browsing to the phpinfo file using the server's IP but not the domain name. Any ideas on how I can get this working using the domain name instead of the IP?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on your computer or on a remote server?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According your second update, you have problem with Listen directive. `nginx` listen only IP-address or Domain name that mentioned in Listen directive. Maximillian gives you right answer. It you put `listen 80` in your configuration file, you'll solve your problem, but there would be wotk only one site, with this listen. If you would like to configure PHP on your domain you could configure `listen yourdomain.com:80`.

Comment: @user1398287 you're welcome. Please mark right answer. :)

Comment: is yourdomain.com not the same as default_server?

Comment: @MaximilianWeigand, well, it's different. `default_server` route all request with unknown domains in headers to this server section, yourdomain.com route add requests contains yourdomain.com in headers to this server section.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to edit

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default ?
```

Then you need to edit it as follows.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

afterward, you have to restart php-fpm and nginx

```
service nginx restart && service php-fpm restart
```

Comment: I tried your config file but Nginx would not restart using this file

Comment: Is cgi.fix_pathinfo set to 0 in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini ?

Comment: in /etc/php.ini yep

Comment: yep I've cleared my cache and even used other browsers, also I've tried using curl http://ip/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

Try with below config for location,

```
location ~ .php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

And do clear cache beforehand.

For your 2nd update try below in server block,

```
listen 127.0.0.1:8000; #your ip with port
server_name  example.com; #domain name
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I also need to setup linux and php environment, so I strictly follow your step to setup it.

I encounter this two issue when I setup the LEMP environment,

a. nginx issue, [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/716415/cant-connect-to-nginx-from-remote-browser-weird-issue) and [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/848591/368057)

b. php-fpm issue, [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570658/how-to-find-my-php-fpm-sock) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43819146/6521116)

I don't encounter the issue you face, so I show the environment for you, you may compare with yours.

**Centos Version**

```
vi /etc/centos-release
```

> CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

**Mysql version**

```
mysql -u root -p
//enter password
```

> Server version: 5.5.52-MariaDB MariaDB Server

**Php version**

```
php -v
```

> PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Nov  6 2016 00:29:02)

**Pear info**

`pear list` // refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119195/yum-install-php-pear-on-centos)

> ```
> Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
> ========================================= 
> Package          Version State
> Archive_Tar      1.3.11  stable
> Console_Getopt   1.3.1   stable
> PEAR             1.9.4   stable
> Structures_Graph 1.0.4   stable
> XML_Util         1.2.1   stable
> ```

**Nginx config file**
 `vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  192.168.236.129;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**info.php** `vi /usr/share/nginx/html/info.php`

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for this, everything was the same apart from I didn't have mysql installed. and my php version was slightly older. I copied over my nginx config file with yours and restarted everything. I found out that php files run when browsing to the phpinfo file using the server's IP but not the domain name.

Comment: check your hosts file to see you domain name bind to which ip， here may be your DNS issue.