# PHP Warning: include_once(Net/SMTP.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, pear, mail-mime

I want to send email by using Gmail. For this, I just run the following command

```
pear install Mail Mail_Mime
```

My php file (filename.php) code is given below

```
<?php
  require_once "Mail.php";
  $from = 'from@gmail.com';
  $to = 'to@gmail.com';
  $subject = 'Hi!';
  $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
  $headers = array(
      'From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject
  );
  $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
          'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
          'port' => '465',
          'auth' => true,
          'username' => 'from@gmail.com',
          'password' => 'password'
      ));
  $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
  if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
      echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
  } else {
      echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
  }
?>
```

When I run this "filename.php" by using below command

```
php filename.php
```

I got the following Error

```
PHP Warning:  include_once(Net/SMTP.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 365
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'Net/SMTP.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 365
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Net_SMTP' not found in /usr/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 366
```

I am using CentOS 7.

Comment: The message is pretty clear, the file Net/SMTP.php is not found

Comment: @Antony I can see `smtp.php` insdei `/usr/share/pear/Mail/`

Comment: Is your PEAR directory in the include_path?

Comment: You should remove the tag `phpmailer`, since you're actually using Pears Mail class, and not phpmailer (which is it's own mail library).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález How can I check that, PEAR directory in the include_path?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Which line should I have to remove, Please suggest to me?

Comment: Please refer this link this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284468/problem-with-php-pear-mail

Comment: You had tagged this question with `phpmailer`. I removed the tag for you.

Comment: @AnandPandey `WARNING: channel "pear.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pear channel-update pear.php.net" to update
WARNING: "pear/Auth_SASL" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Auth_SASL2"
Did not download optional dependencies: pear/Auth_SASL, use --alldeps to download automatically
pear/Net_SMTP requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.10.1), installed version is 1.9.4
pear/Net_SMTP can optionally use package "pear/Auth_SASL" (version >= 1.0.5)
pear/Net_Socket requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.10.1), installed version is 1.9.4
install failed`

Comment: @AnandPandey When I run `pear install Net_SMTP` It gives me the above Error which is mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: use --alldeps to download automatically

Comment: @AnandPandey like this `pear install Net_SMTP --alldeps` ?

Comment: Simplest way to see `include_path` is `phpinfo()`. Alternatively, `ini_get()`. But adding paths is something you'd be doing somewhere in your code; if you need to ask, you aren't doing it.

Comment: You're not looking for `/usr/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php`, but for `Net/SMTP.php`. Do you have a Net folder in pear/mail?

Comment: pear install --alldeps

Comment: this will help you    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119195/yum-install-php-pear-on-centos

Comment: I have one question. If I have to install `pear-1.10.1` on centos. So what should be the command for installing this specific version 1.10.1 by using `yum install`

Answer (score 16):

Now it's Working for me. I just use the below Steps to resolved this :

```
1. pear upgrade --force --alldeps http://pear.php.net/get/PEAR-1.10.1
2. pear clear-cache
3. pear update-channels
4. pear upgrade
5. pear upgrade-all
6. pear install Auth_SASL
7. pear install pear/Net_SMTP
```

After that everything is working fine.

Thanks Everyone.

Comment: Where to use this?

Comment: you saved my day... :)

Comment: @CecilPaul These are linux commands. You run them on the server

Answer (score 3):

For Windows Machines -

Net_SMTP is one implementation of the SMTP protocol. You'll need to install that extension. By running the following command in CMD.

```
pear install Net_SMTP
```

Be sure your have pear installed and setup in your environment path.

Comment: Thank you @Quickee your command resolved my problem! Much appreciated.